オラクル社のJDKのインストールに関しての質問です
EclipseでJavaを打ち込み、コマンドプロンプトでコンパイルするために、javacコマンドを活用する必要があるため、オラクル社のJDKというソフトウエアが必要だというところまで調べました。
JDKのダウンロードと解凍は出来たのですが、インストールができません。
これらをChatGPTに質問して出てきた回答も、試してみたものの上手くいきませんでした。
詳しい方、ご協力をお願いできないでしょうか？

ChatGPTに質問して出てきた回答は以下になります。

OracleのJDKインストーラが表示されない場合、いくつかの原因が考えられます。以下に主な原因を挙げます：

ダウンロードの失敗
ファイルが正しくダウンロードされていない場合、インストーラが正常に実行されないことがあります。ファイルが途中で壊れていると、インストールプロセスが開始されません。
対策: ダウンロードしたファイルのサイズがOracleの公式サイトで示されているサイズと一致するか確認してください。ファイルが小さすぎる場合、再度ダウンロードしてみてください。

ファイルの拡張子が変更されている
ダウンロード中や後に、ファイルの拡張子が何らかの理由で変更された場合、インストーラが認識されないことがあります。通常、Windows用のJDKインストーラは.exeファイルです。
対策: ダウンロードしたファイルが正しい拡張子（exe）を持っているか確認してください。

セキュリティソフトによるブロック
セキュリティソフトがインストーラを誤ってブロックしている場合があります。これは、ウイルスやマルウェアの疑いがあるとセキュリティソフトが判断するためです。
対策: 一時的にセキュリティソフトを無効化して、インストーラを再度実行してみてください。また、セキュリティソフトのログを確認し、インストーラがブロックされていないか確認することも有効です。

管理者権限の不足
インストーラを実行するためには管理者権限が必要です。通常、管理者権限がないと、インストーラが実行されないか、インストールが途中で止まることがあります。
対策: インストーラを右クリックして「管理者として実行」を選択してみてください。

互換性の問題
インストーラが現在のオペレーティングシステムと互換性がない場合、実行できないことがあります。特に、64ビット版と32ビット版の間で互換性の問題が発生することがあります。
対策: OracleのJDKダウンロードページで、使用しているオペレーティングシステムに適したバージョンのJDKをダウンロードしているか確認してください。

システム環境の問題
システム環境変数が正しく設定されていない場合や、既存のJavaインストールが問題を引き起こしている場合があります。
対策: 既存のJavaインストールをアンインストールしてから、再度JDKをインストールしてみることを検討してください。




何が如何なっているか如何すれば良いかが分からないなら、いったんすべてアンインストールして、JDKを含んだPleiades All in OneのFull EditionとPleiades プラグインをダウンロードしてインストールするのが良いのでは？ このJDKはおそらくオラクル社の中でOpenJDKと言われている物でしょう。商用サポート有りであるOracleJDKでなくても使えると思われます。JDKの新しいリリース・モデ および提供ライセンスについて, 【Java】OpenJDKってどれ選べばいいの？

「解凍は出来たけどインストール出来ない」が、手順自体が分からないのか、何か作業をしたけどエラー等が出てうまくいかないなのかを明確にしてください。また、使用している OS についての情報も記載してください。 / ChatGPT に頼るより、公式のマニュアルを参照しましょう。 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html

こんな記事も参考に。JAVA 理論と実装、Pleiades All in One の導入から起動まで緊急解説

皆様ありがとうございます。
手順自体が判らないので、公式マニュアルを参考にしつつPleiades All in OneのFull EditionとPleiades プラグインをダウンロードしてみることにします。
また、質問内容自体も編集しておきます。
資料にも目を通させていただきます

OS が明記されていないので抽象的な表現になりますが、(JDK に限らず) インストール用のファイルとして「インストーラ (exe 形式)」と「圧縮ファイル」がある場合、 通常はインストーラを選択してください。
ほとんどの場合は GUI のガイドに従って進めれば適切なパスへのインストールや設定も行ってくれるので、詳しくない人向けと言えます。
圧縮ファイル形式を選んだ場合、自分自身でインストール先を考えたりインストール後の設定を行う必要があるので、 ある程度理解している人向け になります。
